# How can I use Custom Loader or Progress View ROKU

Tags: spinner, roku, brightscript

I want to create a custom spinner in My ROKU App like netflix.How can I implement it.Please guide me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing scene graph, the easy way is to use this class:

https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/BusySpinner

Otherwise, you'd have to use the 2d api, which is a hassle.

Answer (score -1):

I have never attempted this for ROKU-- and I have ROKU myself-- but does this site help?

http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Design+Guidelines

Or this?

Create Your Own ROKU Channel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32A1ktr_QEY

I hope this answer was helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Ok.I will try.Thank you so much.